# Why doesn't geom_hline generate a legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have some code that is plots a histogram of some values, along with a few horizontal lines to represent reference points to compare against. However, ggplot is not generating a legend for the lines.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

## Siumlate an equal mix of uniform and non-uniform observations on [0,1]
x <- data.frame(PValue=c(runif(500), rbeta(500, 0.25, 1)))
y <- c(Uniform=1, NullFraction=0.5) %>% data.frame(Line=names(.) %>% factor(levels=unique(.)), Intercept=.)
ggplot(x) +
    aes(x=PValue, y=..density..) + geom_histogram(binwidth=0.02) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=Intercept, group=Line, color=Line, linetype=Line),
               data=y, alpha=0.5)
```

I even tried reducing the problem to just plotting the lines:

```
ggplot(y) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=Intercept, color=Line)) + xlim(0,1)
```

and I still don't get a legend. Can anyone explain why my code isn't producing plots with legends?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `show_guide = FALSE` for `geom_hline`. If you turn this on then the legend will appear. Also, alpha needs to be inside of `aes` otherwise the colours of the lines will not be plotted properly (on the legend). The code looks like this:

```
ggplot(x) +
  aes(x=PValue, y=..density..) + geom_histogram(binwidth=0.02) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=Intercept, colour=Line, linetype=Line, alpha=0.5),
             data=y, show_guide=TRUE)
```

And output:

[image]